# Need help with associate law and binary problems that deal with division

Tags: abstract-algebra, advice

I understand how to prove the associate law as long as a*b has no division operator in it

I flummoxed when trying to follow 
division. I can’t figure it out.

I will give you 2 examples and you 
have go through the steps to  show it
is or not associative

1. a*b=(a+b)/(ab-1)
2. a*b = a*b/(a+b)

Ok I try half of 2.

(a*b)*c=(((a*b)/(a+b))*c)/((ab/(a+b))+c))

```
   =(abc/(ac+bc))/(ab+ca+bc)/(a+b)

   = abc(a+b)/((ac+bc)(ab+ca+bc))
```

I am basing my work of Pinters book A book of Abstract algebra 
Chapter 3 Solution A3

So I explain what I do . Let a = ab/(a+c).c=b
In the numerator it’s says to multiply a*b. In the
denominator I add a+b and do that and the rest is
simplification.

Comment: What have you tried? And what set are you working over? (For instance, are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?)

Comment: Looked at one example and was right in assumption but when applying it to another I was wrong so am flumoxxed

Answer (score 1):

The first is not associative, take $c=1$, then
\begin{align*}
(a\ast b)\ast 1&=\frac{a\ast b +1}{a\ast b-1}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{\frac{a+b}{ab-1}+1}{\frac{a+b}{ab-1}-1}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{a+b+ab-1}{a+b-ab+1}\nonumber
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a\ast(b\ast 1)&=\frac{a+(b\ast 1)}{a(b\ast 1)-1}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{a+\frac{b+1}{b-1}}{a\frac{b+1}{b-1}-1}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{ab-a+b+1}{ab+a-b+1}\nonumber\\
\end{align*}
The second operation is transitive, indeed 
\begin{align*}
(a\ast b)\ast c&=\frac{(a\ast b)c}{a\ast b +c}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{\frac{ab}{a+b}c}{\frac{ab}{a+b}+c}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{\frac{abc}{a+b}}{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a+b}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{abc}{ab+ac+bc}\nonumber
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a\ast(b\ast c)&=\frac{a(b\ast c)}{a+(b\ast c)}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{a(\frac{bc}{b+c})}{a+\frac{bc}{b+c}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{abc}{ab+ac+bc}\nonumber
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks ! Atleast one of my examples shows equality 